# Better Alternative than Sprite Masks in Unity?

Tags: unity, sprites, game-mechanics, fog-of-war

[image]

I am have blank sqaure sprite as a Fog of war and I am spawning multiple sprites masks when the player starts moving, through this I am to get this effect where only places where the player has travelled is revealed. But this causes too many Spritmasks to be spawned which significantly lowers the performance. Is there a better way for fog of war reveal other than sprite masks?

Comment: Presumably you've [searched "how to make fog of war effect in Unity"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+2d+fog+of+war&ia=web)? How have you tried implementing the guidance you've found so far?